# Resize view in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am so confused about UIScrollView.
I'm working with a view contains many other views. And that view placed in a UIScrollView.
How can I change height of this view?
I've tried so many ways but they didn't work. I tried to change frame by CGRect but view's child went wrong.

Comment: Use constraints. You can change the constant value of height constraint, that will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using constraints using auto layout.If all the constraints are justified then the there will be no warning.At that moment the scrollview will fit all the views under its contents view and mange the content size of it by itself.
If you want to increase any view in the scrollview to increase in height you may increase the height constraint and the scrollview will manage the constentsize by itself.